# Manually scale out the number of VMs in the scale set to 5 using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have a virtual machine scale set to be deployed to azure by using Azure power shell and set instance count to 1.The VMSS includes a storage account,
load balancer, public IP address. and six Standard_A1 Windows virtual machines (VMs)that run Internet Information Services (IIS). All components are deployed to a resource group.

I need to increase the instance count to support increase load on IIS.And, manually scale out the number of VMs in the scale set to 5.

I have written the power shell command like this:

```
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName CorpWebRG –VMScalesSetName
CorpWebVMSS 
$vmss.Sku.Capacity = 5
Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName CorpWebRG -Name CorpWebVMSS -
VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Looks like this solution does not meet the goal. What am I missing? and what extra I need to do? Please help and suggest a link. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific about how it doesn't meet the goal? It would likely help us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any error message while running the above code?
Refer the below article to manually scaling a scale set out and in:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview#manually-scaling-a-scale-set-out-and-in

Answer (score 3):

> I have a virtual machine scale set to be deployed to azure by using
>   Azure power shell and set instance count to 1.

Use this command `$vmss.Sku.Capacity = 5` to upgrade capacity to 5, will not increase VMSS running instances, just upgrade `the maximum numbers of vmss instances`.

If you want to instance running vmss instances, you can use Azure portal select `Scale to a specific instance count` to increase running vmss instances, like this:

[image]

More information about `Scale to a specific instance count`, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-portal).

Hope this helps.

---

**Update:**

> To create autoscale rules based on a schedule rather than host
>   metrics, use the Azure portal. Schedule-based rules **cannot** currently
>   be created with Azure PowerShell.

More information about autoscale based on a schedule, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-autoscale-powershell#autoscale-based-on-a-schedule).

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other additional power shell script I need to add? If I would like to do this by powershell script only.

Comment: @AskMe As far as I know, Azure powershell does not support set VMSS specific instance count, I have update my answer, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Get current scale set:

```
$vmss = Get-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -VMScaleSetName "myScaleSet"
```

##### Set and update the capacity of your scale set:

```
$vmss.sku.capacity = 5
Update-AzVmss -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup" -Name "myScaleSet" -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

Ref link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-manage-powershell#change-the-capacity-of-a-scale-set